# Reading merged excel data in vb.net using ssis

Tags: .net

I got into a tricky issue here. I am working with SSIS tool set to import data from certain files. One of these is an excel spreadsheet. The problem is while picking data from merged cells. Here is a detailed version of the issue -

RowNo       ColA       ColB
    1       Value1
    2                   XYZ

In the above example, **Value1** is merged across row 1 & 2. I am looking to pick up value in ColB irrespective of whether the value in ColA is merged or not.
Curerntly this doesn't happen in my code.

Further details - 
I am using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 as a provider to form a connection. Using a select query to fetch data -
SELECT ColA
FROM 
WHERE CoLB='XYZ'

I would expect this to return **Value1** which obviously is not hapening since it is merged across two rows.

Can someone please help on this one. This is really taking a toll!!

Answer (score 0):

Created a VB code to capture the merged cell value separately. Then looped again to get the other values and updated a virtual dataset with these values.
A little slow, but it works for me!!